# ReactJs how to render pair-value of assoc array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How to render pair-value of assoc array?
I have assoc array:

```
let data = ["foo": 3, "bar": 5, "baz": 6];
```

and I need to render it in my component. 
I try something like this:

```
let content = data.map((value, index) => {
  return (
    <div key={index}}>
      {index}: {value}
    </div>
  );
});
```

But it does not work.

Comment: `let data = ["foo": 3, "bar": 5, "baz": 6];` is this valid?

Comment: That's not a valid array!

Comment: Associative arrays do not exist in javascript

Answer (score 9):

If you have an object, and you want to iterate the keys and values of the object, use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get an array of key/value pairs. Iterate the array of pairs with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and get the key (`k`) and value (`v`) using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const data = { foo: 3, bar: 5, baz: 6 };

const Example = ({ data }) =>
  Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) => (
    <div key={k}>
      {k}: {v}
    </div>
  ));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

That is not a valid array. You need an object by the looks of it:

```
let data = {foo: 3, bar: 5, baz: 6};
```

You can then do:

```
let content = Object.keys(data).map(key => {
  return (
    <div key={key}>
      {`${key}: ${data[key]}`}
    </div>
  );
});
```

---

**Demo**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let data = {foo: 3, bar: 5, baz: 6};
    let content = Object.keys(data).map(key => {
      return (
        <div key={key}>
          {`${key}: ${data[key]}`}
        </div>
      );
    });
    return <div>{content}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = [{"foo": 3}, {"bar": 5}, {"baz": 6}];

  const content1 = data.map((value, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          {index}: {JSON.stringify(value)}
        </div>
      );
    });

  const content2 = data.map((value, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          {Object.keys(value)[0]}: {Object.values(value)[0]}
        </div>
      );
    });
```

> Output1

```
0: {"foo":3}
1: {"bar":5}
2: {"baz":6}
```

> Output2

```
 foo: 3
 bar: 5
 baz: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it. one way could be

```
    const data = { foo: 3, bar: 5, baz: 6 };
    createList() { 
        let items=[];
        for (const [index, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
            items.push(<div key={index}}>{index}: {value}</div>)
        }
        return items;    
    }
    render ( {this.createList();} )
```